# search for a string and replace the entire line from a file

Tags: powershell

I want to search for a string in a file and replace the entire line with a value returned from a command. But for some reason the script does not update the value in the file.

Ex: Search for $FileName in the file and replace that line with the value $FileName=truncate_20190523.log from $key variable which has the value derived from the $NewFile variable.

```
$LogName = "Test.Log"

$FullPath = "\\etldev\logs"

$NewFile = Get-ChildItem -Path '\\etldev\logs\truncate_*' | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

$Key = "`$FileName`=$NewFile"

$Line = Get-Content -Path $FullPath\$LogName | Select-String `$FileName` | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line

(Get-Content -Path $FullPath\$LogName -Raw).Replace('$Line', $Key)| Set-Content -Path $FullPath\$LogName
```

Comment: `(Get-Content 'input.txt') -replace ('.*' + [regex]::Escape($FileName) + '.*'), $Key | Set-Content 'output.txt'`

Comment: @Ansgar: Thank you. I tried the regex function and it replaced the entire file with the input value and that's not what I was looking for. It has to replace only the line that matches the searched string.

Comment: The code I posted should replace lines that contain the value of `$FileName` with the value of `$Key` and leave everything else untouched. If you got a different result you didn't run the code that I posted.

Comment: May be I should've explained in a better way. I want to replace the line containing the name "$FileName" with the value from $Key. Here's the contents of the test.log file before and after running the script.
Before : $FileName = truncate_20190522.log           After: $FileName = truncate_20190523.log

Comment: Ah, I see. You want to search for the *string* "$FileName", not the value of a *variable* `$FileName`. `(Get-Content 'input.txt') -replace ('^\$FileName.*'), $Key | Set-Content 'output.txt'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your $Line variable. There should be the whole log file in it.
Try it like that:

```
$Content = Get-Content -Path $Path
$Line = $Content | Select-String -Pattern "Pattern" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line
$Index = $Content.IndexOf($Line) 
$Content[$Index]= "Replaced"
$Content | Out-File -FilePath $Path -Force
```

Comment: Thank you. I fixed my code per your suggestion and added your code to it and it worked.

Comment: Please accept it as an answer when it solved your problem.